# Trouble with installing cabal on mac

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

```
wget http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-install-0.14.0/cabal-install-0.14.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf cabal-install-0.14.0.tar.gz
cd cabal-install-0.14.0
sh bootstrap.sh
```

There are the commands that I used, when I run `bootstrap.sh`, I get this error:

```
Configuring cabal-install-0.14.0...
Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
mtl >=2.0 && <3

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Configuring the cabal-install package failed
```

That's what I get when I sshed into my school linux computer,

but on my local machine,

I get this error:

```
Configuring cabal-install-1.16.0.2...
Building cabal-install-1.16.0.2...
Preprocessing executable 'cabal' for cabal-install-1.16.0.2...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id HTTP-4000.2.5-f347025199b192c3cf6b1cde4d698a13
    (use -v for more information)

Error during cabal-install bootstrap:
Building the cabal-install package failed
```

Any solutions?
I've tried some solutions on google, but none of it worked...

Comment: How about MacPorts? I use the Haskell Platform from MacPorts and IIRC the installation was easy.

Comment: The standard solution to getting access to cabal-install is to download the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/). It is the first stop to getting access to ghc and cabal-install.  If you have constraints that prevent this could you include them in your question.

Comment: The first one, for `cabal-install-0.14.0`, looks like there is an `mtl-1.*` installed. The regex `MTL_VER_REGEXP="[12]\."` accepts `mtl-1.*`, but the build-depends don't. Changing the regex to `"[2]\." should fix that. For the second, it looks like something is broken in your package db. Run `ghc-pkg check` to see whether that detects a broken `HTTP`. You could also ask bootstrap to be more verbose, `VERBOSE="-v2" ./bootstrap.sh` would, I think, cause sufficient information to be output.

Comment: I sent a patch for the regexp problem Daniel F mentions. You could see if the attempted patch of [bootstrap.sh](https://raw.github.com/michaelt/cabal/master/cabal-install/bootstrap.sh) works. There is something very wrong with the other build. Did you have an old ghc and forget to delete the .ghc directory? (That looks like one possibility)

Comment: The long package id hash after HTTP with the second problem means that cabal-install, or ghc-pkg, knows about an HTTP library you once had installed but can't find it; a typical cause might be that you deleted an old `~/.cabal` directory or haskell platform installation, and thus the libraries themselves -- but not the package.conf directory associated with it. If you do `ghc-pkg list` there will be one or more package.conf.d directories mentioned and you can deduce which should be deleted (if this is indeed the trouble.)

Comment: Thank you so much, Daniel Fischer and applicative, it worked. I still can't get it to work on my local machine, but it works on my school linux server. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on a Mac with Haskell Platform installed.

Running `ghc-pkg recache` solved it.